# Shiro JndiLdapRealm authorization against LDAP

Tags: ldap, shiro

The [JavaDoc for Shiro class JndiLdapRealm](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/ldap/JndiLdapRealm.html) explicitly says that authorization is by default disabled and that authorization against an LDAP server should be implemented by the user by subclassing and overriding the **[`JndiLdapRealm#doGetAuthorizationInfo`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.shiro/shiro-core/1.2.2/org/apache/shiro/realm/ldap/JndiLdapRealm.java#JndiLdapRealm.doGetAuthorizationInfo%28org.apache.shiro.subject.PrincipalCollection%29)** method.
Is there sample code on how to do that including handling the communication / protocol with the LDAP server available anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should implement your own LdapRealm extending JndiLdapRealm.
In this implementation, you would override queryForAuthorizationInfo() ; here is a simple example :

```java
protected AuthorizationInfo queryForAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals, LdapContextFactory ldapContextFactory) throws NamingException {

String username = (String) getAvailablePrincipal(principals);

// Perform context search
LdapContext ldapContext = ldapContextFactory.getSystemLdapContext();

Set<String> roleNames;

try {
  roleNames = getRoleNamesForUser(username, ldapContext);
} finally {
  LdapUtils.closeContext(ldapContext);
}

return buildAuthorizationInfo(roleNames);
}

protected AuthorizationInfo buildAuthorizationInfo(Set<String> roleNames) {
return new SimpleAuthorizationInfo(roleNames);
}

protected Set<String> getRoleNamesForUser(String username, LdapContext ldapContext) throws NamingException {
Set<String> roleNames;
roleNames = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

//SHIRO-115 - prevent potential code injection:
String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=*)(CN={0}))";
Object[] searchArguments = new Object[]{ username };

NamingEnumeration answer = ldapContext.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchArguments, searchCtls);

while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
  SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();

  if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    log.debug("Retrieving group names for user [" + sr.getName() + "]");
  }

  Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();

  if (attrs != null) {
    NamingEnumeration ae = attrs.getAll();
    while (ae.hasMore()) {
      Attribute attr = (Attribute) ae.next();

      if (attr.getID().equals("memberOf")) {

        Collection<String> groupNames = LdapUtils.getAllAttributeValues(attr);

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
          log.debug("Groups found for user [" + username + "]: " + groupNames);
        }

        Collection<String> rolesForGroups = getRoleNamesForGroups(groupNames);
        roleNames.addAll(rolesForGroups);
      }
    }
  }
}
```