# Is There A Generic Way To Search For LDAP Groups With Shiro?

Tags: ldap, shiro

I am using `org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.DefaultLdapRealm` to authenticate against LDAP (using `ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389/dc=example,dc=com` as an example).

However, when I try to check for Roles it always fails. It turns out that the DefaultLdapRealm returns null when searching for groups.

```
/**
 * Method that should be implemented by subclasses to build an
 * {@link AuthorizationInfo} object by querying the LDAP context for the
 * specified principal.</p>
 *
 * @param principals          the principals of the Subject whose AuthenticationInfo should be queried from the LDAP server.
 * @param ldapContextFactory factory used to retrieve LDAP connections.
 * @return an {@link AuthorizationInfo} instance containing information retrieved from the LDAP server.
 * @throws NamingException if any LDAP errors occur during the search.
 */
protected AuthorizationInfo queryForAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals,
                                                      LdapContextFactory ldapContextFactory) throws NamingException {
    return null;
}
```

There is a [similar question from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173492/shiro-jndildaprealm-authorization-against-ldap), however, it looks like a copy of the code from the [ActiveDirectoryRealm](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/realm/activedirectory/ActiveDirectoryRealm.java#L158).

Does *everyone* who wants to use LDAP with groups using Shiro have to write a custom Realm?

Couldn't the DefaultLdapRealm take a property that configures the search filter for groups but doesn't require extra code (like the userDNTemplate is used for login)?

Does such a Realm already exist in a maven dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest issue is there are many many different ways to store things in LDAP, there is a hand full of common techniques though.

op moved this to a mailing list thread: http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/New-LDAP-Realm-Proposal-tp7581200p7581291.html